# :last-child works, :first-child doesn't

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I have an `aside` with two `<div class="sku">` elements. I'm trying to use CSS to manipulate the `:first-child` but it doesn't work. However, when trying to access the `:last-child` it does.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sobh9zzm/)

**HTML**

```
<aside>
  <h1>Product Name</h1>
  <div class="sku">
    <h3>
      100 – Small
    </h3>
    <div class="dimension">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class="title">
            Product Dimensions
          </span>
          <span class="specs">
            23.75w
            x
            17.75h
            x
            28d
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="sku">
    <h3>
      200 – Large
    </h3>
    <div class="dimension">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <span class="title">
            Product Dimensions
          </span>
          <span class="specs">
            29.75w
            x
            17.75h
            x
            28d
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</aside>
```

**CSS**

```
.sku:first-child { 
  display:none !important; /*doesn't hide the first child*/
}

.sku:last-child { 
  display:none !important; /*does hide the first child*/
}
```

Why won't `:first-child` select the first div?

Comment: Please share your code and what you are trying to accomplish.  Telling us something isn't working isn't helpful without more information.

Comment: This is because `.sku` is not the **first** child of the `aside` element. CSS pseudo-classes such as `:first-child`, `:last-child`, `nth-child()`,... look through the children tree of the parent to match the proper child element, not a combination of `element.class`.

Comment: `dev.sku` isn't the first child — `h3` is. Try `:first-of-type` instead.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot use `:first-child` psuedo class since `.sku` is not the first child. A better option is to use either `:first-of-type` (for first child) or `:nth-of-type` (which can accept a number or an equation) pseudo classes:

```
.sku:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
}
```

[**Updated Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/sobh9zzm/1/)

Answer (score 2):

The :first-child means the first child. Which is in this case the H1. So this does not work. You can use:

```
h1 + .sku { }
```

But only if this is the order you place your HTML.

Comment: So why does :last-child work then?

Comment: Because the .sky is the last child of the parent element. You have 3 elements on that level, `h1 + .sku + .sku` which :last-child is the last sku. If you had a h2 after the last sku. It doesnt work.

Comment: @greetification Since none of CSS pseudo-classes respect to class names themselves, I'd go with this adjacent sibling selector which is supported even in IE7.